# Typescript writing angular $httpprovider defaults

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am trying to write a global angular `$httpprovider` defaults in *TypeScript*. Here is my code, what I have currently.

```
export class JSONDateParser {
    private httpProvider:any;
    public static $inject = [
        $httpProvider
    ];
    constructor($httpProvider:any) {
        console.log("Json Date Parser Defaults");
        this.httpProvider = $httpProvider; // This gives me runtime error 
                                           // as this is a referencing angular.
    }
}

// here is my reference registering this
app.config(JSONDateParser);
```

1. How can I write angularjs `httpProvider` defaults in Typescript?
2. Also how can I apply lambda syntax for constructor in Typescript.
3. If I assign `httpProvider` variable as `ng.IHttpProvider` type, complier complains `this.httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse`, `transformResponse` is not resolved. I see that in type definition for angular.d.ts *(1.2.x)* it is not defined, but it should be there right? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We would need a bit adjusted syntax:

```
// define parser
export class JSONDateParser {

    constructor(private $httpProvider:any) {
        console.log("Json Date Parser Defaults");
    }
}

// register it
app.config(['$httpProvider', ($httpProvider) => new JSONDateParser($httpProvider)]);
```

Angular `.config()` is not as flexible as `.service()` or `.controller()`.

So we have to pass all the params into controller inside of the initialization arrow function. I also used array notation, which is the way - to later not suffer by minifying

Also, if we delcare param as private:

```
constructor(private $httpProvider:any) {
...
```

compiler will create a field and assign it so later we can do `this.$httpProvider`